# discount formula not calculating discount for less than 5%

Tags: php, html, sql

I have used this code to calculate discount between the selling price and MRP of products by fetching them from the database. The discount formula is working fine but when it comes to calculate discount lesser than 5%, its showing 0% discount in its place. I'm not able to figure it out. Help Appreciated.

```
<?php
$mainsql="SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Brand, MRP, SP 
FROM producttable 
WHERE ProductID='".$id."'";
$mainquery=mysql_query($mainsql);
$main=mysql_fetch_row($mainquery);

$mrp=number_format($main[3], 0, ' ', ',');
$sp=number_format($main[4], 0, ' ', ',');

$discount=(($mrp-$sp)/$mrp)*100;

<h3>Discount: You save<span class=\"percentage_style\"> ".round($discount, 0)."</span>%</h3>
?>
```

Comment: Please can you supply a dump of data. I have run a few tests and haven't been able to replicate

Comment: can you provide some MRP and SP values stored in DB. (without number format)

Comment: like for MRP - 6500 and SP - 6250 .. its showing 0% discount when it actually becomes 3% discount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats because you are doing the number formatting before doing the arithmetic operation

The correct way should be -

```
$mrp = 6500 ;
$sp = 6250 ;

$dis = round((($mrp-$sp)/$mrp)*100) ;
echo $dis ;
```

It will be 4% since without round its around 3.8461538461538

Once you do the calculation you can use the number format for the display part.

Comment: hey thanks removing the number_format also did the trick .. thanks alot